# SQL Server: Does an UPDATE statement is faster if the table has indexes?

Tags: sql-server

I need to insert 1.5 Million records into a table with the following layout:

```sql
MyEdition
(
    MyEdition_ID INT,
    MyEntity_ID INT,
    copyType_ID INT,
    MyEdition_CopyText VARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

I'm disabling all the INDEXES (both the clustered and non-clustered) and TRIGGERS on the table before inserting records from a temp table.

I need to strip-out all the HTML tags (except Bold, Italic and Underline tags) from the `MyEdition_CopyText` column from all 1.5M rows, so I'm performing an `UPDATE` on the table which uses a SQL function to strip out HTML tags within the `MyEdition_CopyText` column.

To summarise what I'm doing:

1. `ALTER INDEX [MyEdition_reindex] ON [MyEdition] DISABLE` (similarly all other indexes)
2. `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyEdition] DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;`
3. `INSERT INTO MyEdition(<columns>) SELECT <columns> FROM <#my_temp_table>`
4. `UPDATE MyEdition SET MyEdition_CopyText = dbo.StripHTML(MyEdition_CopyText)`
5. `REBULID INDEXES`
6. `ENABLE TRIGGERS`

The `UPDATE` statement is taking a little while, so I wonder if this is because all the indexes were disabled? What would be the best approach to strip out the HTML characters from the column?

Any suggestions on how this could be improved? How SQL Server make use of indexes whilst performing an `UPDATE` operation?

I'm using the following SQL function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[StripOutHTML]
(
    @HTMLText VARCHAR(max),
    @stripDisallowedOnly BIT
)
returns VARCHAR(max) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @Start INT
      DECLARE @End INT
      DECLARE @Length INT 

      -- Replace the HTML entity & with the '&' character (this needs to be done first, as  
      -- '&' might be double encoded as '&amp;')  
      SET @Start = Charindex('&amp;', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = @Start + 4 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, '&') 
            SET @Start = Charindex('&amp;', @HTMLText) 
            SET @End = @Start + 4 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Replace the HTML entity < with the '<' character  
      SET @Start = Charindex('&lt;', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = @Start + 3 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, '<') 
            SET @Start = Charindex('&lt;', @HTMLText) 
            SET @End = @Start + 3 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Replace the HTML entity > with the '>' character  
      SET @Start = Charindex('&gt;', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = @Start + 3 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, '>') 
            SET @Start = Charindex('&gt;', @HTMLText) 
            SET @End = @Start + 3 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Replace the HTML entity & with the '&' character  
      SET @Start = Charindex('&amp;amp;', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = @Start + 4 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, '&') 
            SET @Start = Charindex('&amp;amp;', @HTMLText) 
            SET @End = @Start + 4 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Replace the HTML entity   with the ' ' character  
      SET @Start = Charindex('&nbsp;', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = @Start + 5 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, ' ') 
            SET @Start = Charindex('&nbsp;', @HTMLText) 
            SET @End = @Start + 5 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Replace any <P>, </P>tags with a <BR>, so they will be replaced with a new line in next step  
      SET @HTMLText = REPLACE(@HTMLText, '<P>', '<br>') 
      SET @HTMLText = REPLACE(@HTMLText, '</P>', '<br>') 

      -- Replace any <BR> tags with a newline  
      SET @Start = Charindex('<br>', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = @Start + 3 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, 
                            Char(13) + Char(10)) 
            SET @Start = Charindex('<br>', @HTMLText) 
            SET @End = @Start + 3 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Replace any  tags with a newline  
      SET @Start = Charindex('<br/>', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = @Start + 4 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, 
                            'CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)') 
            SET @Start = Charindex('<br/>', @HTMLText) 
            SET @End = @Start + 4 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Replace any  tags with a newline  
      SET @Start = Charindex('<br />', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = @Start + 5 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, 
                            'CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)') 
            SET @Start = Charindex('<br />', @HTMLText) 
            SET @End = @Start + 5 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Remove anything between  tags  
      SET @Start = Charindex('<', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = Charindex('>', @HTMLText, Charindex('<', @HTMLText)) 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            IF @stripDisallowedOnly = 1 
              BEGIN 
                  IF ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 2)) <> '<B' ) 
                     AND ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 3)) <> '</B' ) 
                     AND ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 2)) <> '<U' ) 
                     AND ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 3)) <> '</U' ) 
                     AND ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 2)) <> '<I' ) 
                     AND ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 3)) <> '</I' ) 
                    BEGIN 
                        SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, '') 
                    END 
                  ELSE 
                    BEGIN 
                        SET @Length = 0 
                    END 
              END 
            ELSE 
              BEGIN 
                  SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, '') 
              END 

            SET @Start = Charindex('<', @HTMLText, @End - @Length) 
            SET @End = Charindex('>', @HTMLText, Charindex('<', @HTMLText, 
                                                 @Start) 
                       ) 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Remove any leading space/carriage return 
      DECLARE @trimchars VARCHAR(10)
      SET @trimchars = CHAR(9)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(32)
         IF @HTMLText LIKE '[' + @trimchars + ']%' SET @HTMLText = SUBSTRING(@HTMLText, PATINDEX('%[^' + @trimchars + ']%', @HTMLText), LEN(@HTMLText))
      RETURN Ltrim(Rtrim(@HTMLText)) 
  END
```

EDIT:

I have tested the following three ways:

1. Update all in one SQL statement.

   `UPDATE MyEdition SET MyEdition_Copy=[dbo].StripOutHTML(MyEdition_Copy, 1)`

-- This approach took 3 hours

1. Updated 10000 records in one batch.

   `DECLARE @min INT, @max INT, @batchSize INT
   SET @batchSize = 10000
   SELECT @min=MIN(MyEdition_id), @max=MAX(MyEdition_id)
   FROM MyEdition
   --PRINT 'MAX:' + CAST(@max AS VARCHAR(50))
   WHILE @min < @max
   BEGIN
       DECLARE @x varchar(max) = ''
       SET @x = 'UPDATE MyEdition SET MyEdition_CopyText=dbo.StripOutHTML(MyEdition_CopyText, 1)'
                   + 'WHERE (copytextedition_id BETWEEN ' + CAST(@min AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' AND ' + CAST((@min + @batchSize -1) AS VARCHAR(50)) + ');'
       Exec(@x)
       PRINT @x
       SET @min = @min + @batchSize
   END`

-- This approach took 5 hours 20 minutes

1. Loaded the values into .Net program, Stripped those characters and saved into the database.

-- This approach took about 24 hours.

Comment: Is it really necessary to use T-SQL to strip out the HTML? T-SQL is vastly inferior to C# in such things. This probably has a high CPU cost as well.

Comment: @usr and who said anything about C# being used here?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar prefer any language to T-SQL, basically.

Comment: @usr OK. Update: Who said anything about any other software written in any language being involved in this project? Could it just be a bulk-insert without any other software being involved?

Comment: In that case I'd consider running the bulk insert through a C# project or use a SQL CLR function. There are libraries for manipulating HTML. T-SQL is vastly under-equipped to deal with this. It is doable, of course, as a last resort.

Comment: @usr ...which is basically a good idea and was my first thought, too, but hey, that's not the question :-)

Comment: Thank you both usr and Thorsten. @usr Are you saying loading all the 1.5 million records into the application layer [VB.Net in my case] and perform string operation to remove the HTML tags, and then re-inserting in the database would be faster/better?

Comment: I can't say it would be faster. It depends on how expensive the T-SQL code is that you're running. Looks very expensive. Certainly it would have been less development effort. And probably your manually written code is bug ridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily an answer in this case, but I want to post this in case it is useful to anyone else who finds this post. Here is another way to do a large update in batches that doesn't involve using dynamic SQL and `EXEC()`, which probably is hurting performance to some degree:

(Note this approach requires SQL 2005 or higher, and a table with a unique key, called "`PKColumn`" in the code below)

```
DECLARE @BatchSize int = 50000;
DECLARE @RowNum int = 1;

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT PKColumn
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PKColumn ASC) BETWEEN @RowNum AND (@RowNum + @BatchSize)
)
UPDATE t1
SET SomeColumn = SomeValue
FROM MyTable t1
INNER JOIN cte
  ON t1.PKColumn=cte.PKColumn;

IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
  BREAK;
ELSE
  BEGIN 
  SET @RowNum = @RowNum + @BatchSize + 1;
  CONTINUE;
  END
END
```

I hope that's everything; I'm writing on the fly from memory without testing.  You can try it, but I think because of your function, it's not going to be any faster.

Answer (score 4):

Indexes only help when you want to restrict the set of data being modified. *In your case an index won't have any effect*, as you update every record anyway. In fact, the update might even be quicker without indexes, if the indexes included the field that was being updated, as every update would cause the index to be changed.

Comment: Thank you, Thorsten. Do you know if there is a better/faster way to deal this case (i.e. to strip out HTML tags from all the rows)?

Comment: Not that I know of. Based on a comment to the question: If possible, do the HTML-stripping before inserting into the database, which was my first thought.

Comment: Thanks, but I would need to apply the same function to strip out the HTML since the data is coming from a legacy database TEXT column. I found that INSERT is very slow when the function was included so I have changed my code to UPDATE like this. I have tried updating records in batches of 10000, but that that approach had taken the same time.

Comment: I am surprised to hear that updating in batches isn't faster.   I have always performed large updates in batches of 50k rows, and it's measurably faster for me.  Conventional wisdom also holds that UPDATES and even INSERTS are faster on tables that have a Clustered Index, but no additional indexes.

Comment: @TabAlleman, please see my edit. This approach took 5 hours 20 minutes.

Comment: Looking at your edit, I am not surprised.  The function you are using, I am pretty sure, is going to force SQL to perform a row-by-row operation.  Doing things in 50k batches, again, I am pretty sure, is only more performant in set-based operations.   I doubt there's much of anything you can do to improve on the speed of the basic update in this case.   Maybe SSIS, but I doubt it.